# CSS dropdown menu lined up with viewport, not parent to impede crazy scrolling

Tags: css

Most CSS dropmenus tend to line up the top of the list of children `<ul>` with the top of the parent `<li>`.

But that  breaks down easily the longer the menus and lengthier the list of children, which then drop out of the view port, create scrolling issues and so forth.

Given [this codepen](https://jsfiddle.net/dvo4/6s8pn7wf/6/)  how can the submenu be aligned with the height of the parent menu, say offset down by 50px ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to offset up to hit the top off the viewport by adding a sub-menu class and changing the relative parent:

```
.li-sub ul {
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 250px !important;
 }
```

Here's the same fiddle but with the adjustments: https://jsfiddle.net/getr0cou/4/

Comment: so each level has to offset based on its position in the array?  Can we not just positin it a a fixed slot at top?

Comment: Check the fiddle now. https://jsfiddle.net/getr0cou/4/

Comment: Yep, that fits better!